# Prestashop 1.6.1 installing template issue

Tags: templates, themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

With the new release (1.6.1) I cannot install a new template I just bought. It requires Themeinstallator, but installation it's not working through traditional template import nor with Themeinstallator module.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem? Maybe it's because the new version, but I haven't found anything about it.

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back (not involving Themeinstallor though). In my case the problem was some Apache FCGI settings that were causing it to timeout before installation completed. The Apache settings that I changed were FcgidIdleTimeout, FcgidProcessLifeTime, FcgidIOTimeout and FcgidBusyTimeout. Of course this only applies if your server is using PHP with Fast CGI.

Comment: I'm not using Fast CGI. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Solved it!

If you are experiencing this problem, just upload the zip file that contains the modules and themes folder to the /themes folder in your FTP. Then just go to your store Backoffice -> Preferences -> Themes -> Add a theme, and will appear under the "import from FTP" combo box.

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: What's the difference between 1.6.1.0 and 1.6.0.14?